# Stripe checkout only working on localhost?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, backend, hosting, checkout

I want to create a Checkout Session using the client and server integration from stripe, to sell my products but I have no experience in backends.

So, I followed these instructions: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart?lang=node%3Fcanceled%3Dtrue

I downloaded the files, added the missing keys and I set up the server using node (`$node server.js`) and searched for "localhost:4242" in my browser, clicked the "Checkout" button and a checkout session was created effortlessly.
->[Screenshot of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW9wc.png)

Now, I thought I simply had to copy these files into my web hosting but obviously, that is not the case since no checkout session is being created no more...

How can I integrate the server checkout on my website?

Comment: Place the files on your server and the "build" the project .. `npm run build` .. This will create a "build" directory that contains your actual files to be served via web server.

Comment: how do I install node to my hosting tho

Comment: You might want to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/deployment or talk to your hosting provider This isn't the kind of things that can be taught in a StackOverflow answer since it depends on many factors (like your hosting provider, what features it offers, how you deploy, etc)